# Spring Data JPA not returning results in Scheduled task

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-scheduled

I have an entity `ExamEvent` and corresponding repository `ExamEventRepository`. I am populating the repository in a service `ExamEventService`. Now, trying to access all the entities through `ExamEventService` (which inturn will call repository) in a scheduled task. But it is returning empty results. Strangely, if I query for all entities from `ExamEventService` from any other service it returns all results. It seems something missing in my scheduled task to access JPA.
Any hints to what could be missing here ?
Thanks.

`ExamEventRepository.java`

```
public interface ExamEventRepository extends JpaRepository<ExamEvent, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ExamEvent> {
    Optional<ExamEvent> findByRequestId(long requestId);
}
```

`ExamEventService.java`

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@Transactional
public class ExamEventService {

    @Autowired
    private ExamEventRepository examEventRepository;

    public List<ExamEvent> findAll() {
        return examEventRepository.findAll();
    }
...
}
```

`SchedulerService.java`

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@Transactional
public class SchedulerService {


    @Autowired
    private ExamEventRepository examEventRepository;


    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${light.otp.schedule.delay-in-ms}")
    public void scheduledTask() {
        List<ExamEvent> search = examEventRepository.findAll();
        log.info("Events==>" + search); // This list is empty here.
     
    }

}
```

`SchedulerConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class SchedulerConfig {


}
```

`Log`

Here, some other service is able to get the results in `main` thread.

```
021-02-08 05:30:36.755  INFO 1774 --- [           main] c.light.request.service.RequestService   : Events==> [ExamEvent(id=3, scribeId=1, candidateId=1, requestId=2, otpGenerated=false, examSchedule=ExamSchedule(id=1, start=2021-02-08T00:30:36.409603Z, end=2021-02-08T02:30:36.409603Z))]
2021-02-08 05:30:41.437  INFO 1774 --- [   scheduling-1] com.light.scheduler.SchedulerService     : Events==> []
```

Another observation is that, after saving `ExamEvent` into repository, its not actually reflecting in H2 DB. I tried with save and flush but still its not visible in DB. The case when data is retrieved, it seem to have got it through in-memory. But in scheduler service it is trying to access DB where data doesn't exist.

Comment: Try removing `@Transactional` from `SchedulerService`

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Tried by removing `@Transactional` from `SchedulerService` but no change in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the root cause of the issue.
It was happening since corresponding unit test was marked `@Transactional`.
Hence, saved data was not flushed to DB and it was not accessible in scheduler thread.
After I removed `@Transactional` from unit test, saved data is flushed and it is accessible from other threads.